# How to prevent this button from running When I use map in react native?

Tags: react-native

My code:

```
{this.state.News.slice(0, this.state.currentShow).map((item) => {
 return (
   <View>
      <View>
         <View>
            <Text>{item.Title}</Text>
             <Text>{item.Content}</Text>
         </View>
         <View>
             <Image source={{uri: item.Image}} />
         </View>
      </View>
      <View>
         <Text>{item.creationTime}</Text>
         <Button onPress={this.gotoNews(item.Id.toString())}>
            <Text>Load More</Text>
         </Button>
      </View>
    </View>
  )
})}
```

Whenever this page is run, Everything is right But why the button onPress runs when the react native screen is loaded!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your button handler call from a function call to a function 
you can use ES6 arrow functions to do this :

```
   <Button onPress={()=>this.gotoNews(item.Id.toString())}>
            <Text>Load More</Text>
   </Button>
```